# Configure and Build LLVM + Clang from Source

Tags: clang, llvm

I tried configure LLVM and Clang and I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: Just read the warnings at the bottom. They say 'not installed'. Install and try again.

Comment: Which package for ctypes . trying sudo apt-get install ctypes but return package not found

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not very with linux. Pls. search on google.

Comment: I installed Ctypes using opam

Comment: Nice. Is it compiling now? Pls. add tags that indicates what OS and distribution you work on.